# DOM element computed style font size too small

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

I'm getting the `font-size` of a `span` within the DOM using the following two approaches in JavaScript code:

```
const element = document.querySelector('h2 span');
const fontSizeObj = element.computedStyleMap().get('font-size');
const fontSizeStr = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
```

This code is getting the same value using two approaches. The first call (`fontSizeObj`) effectively returns the following:

```
{value: 25.600000381469727, unit: "px"}
```

While the second call (`fontSizeStr`) returns the following:

```
"25.6px"
```

These values are consistent; which is good.

There is no direct CSS styling on the `span`, but there is direct styling on the *parent* `h2` through a stylesheet, as follows: `font-size: 5rem;`

Looking in the (Chrome) console at the *computed* `font-size` of the `span` I see that it is:

```
80px
```

This console value is considerably different from the values returned above. This console value also corresponds with the *viewed/rendered* size of the text in the browser.

If I set the value of the element `font-size` to either of the returned values then the displayed text size shrinks dramatically, obviously.

**So, how do I get the actual computed font-size of the text in the `span`?**

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's the thing… In trawling around the Internet I recall reading somewhere that the changes to the styling can happen asynchronously with respect to the thread from which you're observing the state.

So, I placed this piece of code into the mix:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(element.computedStyleMap().get('font-size'));
}, 0);
```

And now I'm getting the *expected* value for the `font-sze` as `80px`.

I can work with that…

***Problem solved.***

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.getComputedStyle in order to calculate the font size of the span.

```
 let spanEl = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

 console.log(window.getComputedStyle(spanEl[0]).fontSize)
```

hope it helps ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, very much appreciated. I tried your recommendation, and I found that it returns "`25.6px`" too. Which is consistent with the first two results but not consistent with the rendered experience, as before. Hmm…

Comment: oh, maybe it is being affected by parent "h2" font size style unit (rem). try to test the result by changing "h2" fon size unit to "px" or sth else. although i know that's weird :)